# How to get order Id in class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Create_Shipping_Method_Form?

Tags: php, magento

How to get order Id in class `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Create_Shipping_Method_Form` ?

I tried out many ways such as, `$this->getQuote->getId();`, `$this->getOrder->getId();` etc etc... But no Use. I am new in magento and extremely new to Its zend based module structure.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: you should get quote id by `$this->getQuote()->getId();`

Answer (score 0):

You can get order ID by:

```
$this->getQuote()->getOrder()->getId();
```

Comment: I cant get it in the `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Create_Shipping_Method_Form` class. By the above code